# Minimizing the matrix norm, equivalence

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

Given matrices $C\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ and $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$, it is known that $X$ minimizes the following

$$\|CC^T-XX^T\|_F^2$$

Can it be proved that such solution X minimizes

$$\|C-X\|_F^2$$

Note that $\|\cdot\|_F$ corresponds to the Frobenius norm.

**Edit**

The question is as I posted it primarily. Note that the dimensions of $C$ and $X$ need to be the same; otherwise $\|C-X\|^2$ would not be possible. With your $X=CU$, what is obtained is $\|CC^T-CC^T\|$. Note that one could trivially set $X=C$ to annihilate Frobenius norm, but that's not the point. Matrix $X$ is supplied externally, and it is known that it minimizes $\|CC^T-XX^T\|^2$; question is: does it also minimize $\|C-X\|^2$?

In the external algorithm, matrix $X$ is obtained as $X=Lsv(C)SV(C)^{1/2}$, where $Lsv(C)$ denotes left-singular vector of $C$, and $SV(C)^{1/2}$ a diagonal matrix with roots of singular values of C. Note that $||C−X||^2$ does not need to be 0 to be minimal.

Comment: Did you maybe mean: $X\in \mathbb R^{k\times n}$ minimizes $\Vert CC^T - X^TX\Vert_F^2$ (or something to that effect)? If not: consider for example $X = CU$ with $UU^T = 1$.

Comment: I edited the question to include some updates that user506901 posted as an answer (now deleted). @user506901: please register your account and/or associate it to your SO one. After that we can see if the stack team can associate this question to your account so that you can edit the question yourself.

Comment: But in this case your matrix $X$ probably has to suffice some additional criteria. As otherwise you could just take $X=C$, which makes both norms $0$, the most *minimal* minimum that can be achieved. So like Sam said, not every $X$ that minimizes the first equation needs to minimize the second. But we need to know the constraints imposed on $X$ (by the external algorithm or whatever), as I guess you cannot just set $X=C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My comment above (consider $X = CU$ with $UU^T=1$) was meant like this:

Any such $X$ minimizes your first norm, since $\|CC^T - XX^T\| = 0$, but

$$\|C - X\| = \|C(1-U)\| \ne 0$$

if $U\ne 1$ (at least in general). So not all matrices minimizing the first expression will also minimize the second.

Comment: In the external algorithm, matrix $X$ is obtained as $X=Lsv(C)SV(C)^{1/2}$, where $Lsv(C)$ denotes left-singular vector of $C$, and $SV(C)^{1/2}$ a diagonal matrix with roots of singular values of $C$. Note that $||C-X||^2$ does not need to be 0 to be minimal.

Comment: @user506901 Aah! So that's what's missing from your question. Now add it in, as otherwise Sam's answer in the correct one, of course.

Comment: @user506901 As Christian has already written in two comments: you should add this additional information to your question. I partially wrote this answer, because I suspected you might write your assumptions on $X$ as a comment to it (as you did). And my crystal ball is broken at the moment. ;)